# What risk does the insulin pump hack carry?

Tags: human-biology, medicine, insulin

Recently, a [OneTouch system was hacked](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/exclusive-j-j-warns-diabetic-123046807.html), potentially allowing any malicious attacks, draining the pump into someone's bloodstream:

> Jay Radcliffe, a diabetic and researcher with cyber security firm Rapid7 Inc, said he had identified ways for a hacker to spoof communications between the remote control and the OneTouch Ping insulin pump, **potentially forcing it to deliver unauthorized insulin injections.**

If this threat is real, what is the theoretical worst-case scenario for a patient with one of these insulin pumps? Is this actually directly life-threatening?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.

Comment: i would suggest googling: total amount of insulin in average device; insulin LD50 for these patients. Should help answering the question.